# How to save a file in hadoop with python

Tags: python, hadoop

**Question:**

I am starting to learn hadoop, however, I need to save a lot of files into it using python.
I cannot seem to figure out what i am doing wrong. Can anyone help me with this?

Below is my code.
I think the `HDFS_PATH` is correct as I didn't change it in the settings while installing.
the `pythonfile.txt` is on my desktop (so is the python code running through the command line).

**Code:**

```
import hadoopy
import os
hdfs_path ='hdfs://localhost:9000/python' 

def main():
    hadoopy.writetb(hdfs_path, [('pythonfile.txt',open('pythonfile.txt').read())])

main()
```

**Output**
When I run the above code all I get is a directory in python itself.

```
iMac-van-Brian:desktop Brian$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfs -ls /python

DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

14/10/28 11:30:05 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
-rw-r--r--   1 Brian supergroup        236 2014-10-28 11:30 /python
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a pretty typical task for the `subprocess` module. The solution looks like this:

```
put = Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-put", <path/to/file>, <path/to/hdfs/file], stdin=PIPE, bufsize=-1)
put.communicate()
```

**Full Example**

Let's assume you're on a server and have a verified connection with hdfs (e.g. you already called a `.keytab`).

You just created a csv from a `pandas.DataFrame` and want to put it into hdfs.

You can then upload the file to hdfs as follows:

```
import os 

import pandas as pd

from subprocess import PIPE, Popen


# define path to saved file
file_name = "saved_file.csv"

# create a pandas.DataFrame
sales = {'account': ['Jones LLC', 'Alpha Co', 'Blue Inc'], 'Jan': [150, 200, 50]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sales)

# save your pandas.DataFrame to csv (this could be anything, not necessarily a pandas.DataFrame)
df.to_csv(file_name)

# create path to your username on hdfs
hdfs_path = os.path.join(os.sep, 'user', '<your-user-name>', file_name)

# put csv into hdfs
put = Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-put", file_name, hdfs_path], stdin=PIPE, bufsize=-1)
put.communicate()
```

The csv file will then exist at `/user/<your-user-name/saved_file.csv`.

*Note* - If you created this file from a python script called in Hadoop, the intermediate csv file may be stored on some random nodes. Since this file is (presumably) no longer needed, it's best practice to remove it so as not to pollute the nodes everytime the script is called. You can simply add `os.remove(file_name)` as the last line of the above script to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that you're writing into a file called '/python' while you intend it to be the directory in which the file is stored

what does

```
hdfs dfs -cat /python
```

show you?

if it shows the file contents, all you need to do is edit your hdfs_path to include the file name (you should delete /python first with -rm) Otherwise, use pydoop (pip install pydoop) and do this:

```
import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs

from_path = '/tmp/infile.txt'
to_path ='hdfs://localhost:9000/python/outfile.txt'
hdfs.put(from_path, to_path)
```

Comment: hdfs dfs -cat /python shows : `14/10/28 21:38:29 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
SEQ/org.apache.hadoop.typedbytes.TypedBytesWritable/org.apache.hadoop.typedbytes.TypedBytesWritable*org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodecOS??Z???'?Nc7R??pythonfile.txtx?c``?cɒ??̼t??̜T??̒
                            ??ʒ??<.?? ?`

Comment: so indeed as I suggested you wrote your data to a *file* called "python" in the root directory. When you 'cat' it you see the contents of the sequenceFile you wrote into (writetb writes a sequenceFile, which is binary - unlike a text file). I don't see in the hadoopy docs a way to write a text file, so use pydoop instead, or keep writing (and reading sequenceFiles). In any case, you need to add the file name to the path, as in my answer above.

Comment: i have tried to store the model from python to hdfs using pydoop. prediction_model is a variable which is having the model.    
    import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs

    from_path = prediction_model
    to_path ='hdfs://192.168.1.101:8020/user/volumata/python_models/churn_model.sav'
    hdfs.put(from_path, to_path)  but i am getting error AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'startswith' like this , where i went wrong can anyone please help me .

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/92321/interacting-with-hadoop-hdfs-using-python-codes.html):

```
import subprocess

def run_cmd(args_list):
        """
        run linux commands
        """
        # import subprocess
        print('Running system command: {0}'.format(' '.join(args_list)))
        proc = subprocess.Popen(args_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        s_output, s_err = proc.communicate()
        s_return =  proc.returncode
        return s_return, s_output, s_err 

#Run Hadoop ls command in Python
(ret, out, err)= run_cmd(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-ls', 'hdfs_file_path'])
lines = out.split('\n')


#Run Hadoop get command in Python
(ret, out, err)= run_cmd(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-get', 'hdfs_file_path', 'local_path'])


#Run Hadoop put command in Python
(ret, out, err)= run_cmd(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-put', 'local_file', 'hdfs_file_path'])


#Run Hadoop copyFromLocal command in Python
(ret, out, err)= run_cmd(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-copyFromLocal', 'local_file', 'hdfs_file_path'])

#Run Hadoop copyToLocal command in Python
(ret, out, err)= run_cmd(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-copyToLocal', 'hdfs_file_path', 'local_file'])


hdfs dfs -rm -skipTrash /path/to/file/you/want/to/remove/permanently
#Run Hadoop remove file command in Python
(ret, out, err)= run_cmd(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-rm', 'hdfs_file_path'])
(ret, out, err)= run_cmd(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-rm', '-skipTrash', 'hdfs_file_path'])


#rm -r
#HDFS Command to remove the entire directory and all of its content from #HDFS.
#Usage: hdfs dfs -rm -r <path>

(ret, out, err)= run_cmd(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-rm', '-r', 'hdfs_file_path'])
(ret, out, err)= run_cmd(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-rm', '-r', '-skipTrash', 'hdfs_file_path'])




#Check if a file exist in HDFS
#Usage: hadoop fs -test -[defsz] URI


#Options:
#-d: f the path is a directory, return 0.
#-e: if the path exists, return 0.
#-f: if the path is a file, return 0.
#-s: if the path is not empty, return 0.
#-z: if the file is zero length, return 0.
#Example:

#hadoop fs -test -e filename

hdfs_file_path = '/tmpo'
cmd = ['hdfs', 'dfs', '-test', '-e', hdfs_file_path]
ret, out, err = run_cmd(cmd)
print(ret, out, err)
if ret:
    print('file does not exist')
```