# Is there a way to ingest specific flat file(.txt or .csv) into HDFS using python script

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I am trying to load a flat file which is there in my local system to HDFS storage.
Actually we have GB's of data to upload into hadoop internal table.
We used the traditional process to load the data like reading the data from a file and splitting into small chunks and then loading each chunk to internal table using hive queries from python. This process is taking hours of time to load into table.

I need an efficient way which can reduce the time while loading data from file to hadoop table. While searching in google i found we can upload the file to hdfs storage and from there we can load the data into table. But i will have to upload the file using python so that it can be automated.

Can anyone please help me out in figuring out a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the processing of the files to hadoop FS instead of doing it on python. In order to load data into hadoop FS you can use the hadoop shell

`hadoop fs -copyFromLocal <local directory>/file.csv <hadoop directory>`

You can trigger this command in python using `subprocess`

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-copyFromLocal', '<local directory>/file.csv', '<hadoop directory>'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
s_output, s_err = proc.communicate()
s_return =  proc.returncode
```

Once your file is in the hadoop filesystem, you can create an hive external table, defining a schema on top of the file.

```
create external table table_name(
 col1 string,
 col2 string,
 ...
 ...
) row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
location '<hadoop directory>'
```

Next when you read from external table, the execution will be much faster.

Reference:

- [How to save a file in hadoop with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606128/how-to-save-a-file-in-hadoop-with-python)
- [Hive External Table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ManagedandExternalTables)